# How to send request from different static IP address to a any website?

Tags: c#, http-request

I am sending HTTP request using C#. (http://codesamplez.com/programming/http-request-c-sharp)

I have dedicated server on.I have purchased more static IPs.

How can I send request using these different IPs.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is bind to a specific network adapter. By default the LocalEndpoint is null so your connection will be to assigned an adapter. You can specify what to bind to using HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate.

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com/");
req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = BindTo;
using (req.GetResponse());

static IPEndPoint BindTo(ServicePoint servicepoint, IPEndPoint remoteendpoint, int retrycount)
{
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Any; //This is where you specify the network adapter's address
    int port = 0; //This in most cases should stay 0. This when 0 will bind to any port available.
    return new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
}
```

[Here is some more information on binding from msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx)

> Use the Bind method if you need to use a specific local endpoint. You
>   must call Bind before you can call the Listen method. **You do not need
>   to call Bind before using the Connect method unless you need to use a
>   specific local endpoint.** You can use the Bind method on both
>   connectionless and connection-oriented protocols.
>
> **Before calling Bind, you must first create the local IPEndPoint from
>   which you intend to communicate data. If you do not care which local
>   address is assigned, you can create an IPEndPoint using IPAddress.Any
>   as the address parameter, and the underlying service provider will
>   assign the most appropriate network address. This might help simplify
>   your application if you have multiple network interfaces. If you do
>   not care which local port is used, you can create an IPEndPoint using
>   0 for the port number. In this case, the service provider will assign
>   an available port number between 1024 and 5000.**
>
> If you use the above approach, you can discover what local network
>   address and port number has been assigned by calling the
>   LocalEndPoint. If you are using a connection-oriented protocol,
>   LocalEndPoint will not return the locally assigned network address
>   until after you have made a call to the Connect or EndConnect method.
>   If you are using a connectionless protocol, you will not have access
>   to this information until you have completed a send or receive.